# What is the market capitalization when there are multiple stock symbols?

Tags: stock-markets

When I searched for the Canadian Tire stock symbol, I got back the following results:

```
Ticker    Market Cap
CTC.TO    8.9B
CTC-A.TO  8.9B
CDNAF     6.8B
CDNTF     -
YAAA.MU   -
YAAA.SG   -
```

Is the market capitalization for Canadian Tire the sum of second column?  Meaning it is at least 24.6B ?  It may even possibly be more because we don't know what the market capitalization is for CDNTF, YAAA.MU and YAAA.SG.  Is that correct?  If not, how do you calculate market capitalization when there are multiple stock symbols for a company?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can see, their market cap is about 17.8B CAD, or 13.6B USD.

The symbols you found are the common and class A shares (which have equal ownership according to their financial statements), and the same shares listed in the US (CDNTF and CDNAF) Munich (YAAA.MU), and Stuutgart (YAAA.SG).

The two classes of shares are additive - the same shares listed in different markets are not.